# "Object 'freq' not found" error applying colour in UpSetR

Tags: r, upsetr

If I run this reprex, I get the required output:

````
``` r
library(UpSetR)
listInput <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13), 
                  two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10), 
                  three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13))

upset(fromList(listInput), order.by = "freq")
```
````

[image]

If I apply a colour, I get the following error.

````
``` r
library(UpSetR)
listInput <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13), 
                  two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10), 
                  three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13))

upset(fromList(listInput), order.by = "freq",
      queries = list(list(query = intersects, params = list("one"), color = "orange", active = T)))
#> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos): object 'freq' not found
```
````

I've looked at the colouring "example 5" in the vignettes, but can't spot my misstep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a column of integers to the dataframe inputted into `upset`.

```
library(UpSetR)
listInput <- list(one = c(1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 13), 
                  two = c(1, 2, 4, 5, 10), 
                  three = c(1, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13))
df <- fromList(listInput)
df$n <- sample(1:nrow(df))

upset(df, order.by = "freq",
      queries = list(list(query = intersects, 
                          params = list("one"), 
                          color = "orange")))
```

[image]

Comment: Can it also colour where "one" intersects with nothing?

Comment: @Carl I completely revised my answer. See the proposed solution. Hope it can help you.